# Display lastName and name in application after retrieve value key in token Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, token

I come back with my problem and I still find no answer

according to the previous solutions I had to develop the function to retrieve information (lastname, name) on the token

```
func loadMemberProfil(completion: ((_ sub : [String: AnyObject]) -> Void)!) {
    // get API profile and Bearer token
    let token = HPWSLoginManager.shared().saveSuccessResponse.token
    let url = URL(string: "http://51.38.36.76:40/api/v1/profile")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    //get information in token
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
            let sub = json["sub"] as! [String: AnyObject]
            if completion != nil{
              completion(sub)
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")

        }
        }.resume()
}
```

And in this function (that I call in viewDidLoad()) I want to display the name and lastname but nothing is displayed when I run the emulator

```
func initTableViewModel() {
    self.loadMemberProfil { (sub) in
        let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(firstName: "\(sub["firstname"])", lastName: "\(sub["lastname"])")
        let tableViewModel = HPMenuViewModel(titlePage: "Menu", array: arrayCellModel, headerMenuViewModel: headerMenu)
        self.tableViewModel = tableViewModel

    }
}
```

but i recover the values in the console please hep me

Comment: You might want to do `myTableView.reloadData()`? Also, you might want to do it in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching but not reloading the data. You might want to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata) to understand the problem.

After you `initTableViewModel` you need to use the code below to reload the data. Note that the `DispatchQueue.main.async` is for doing that in the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thX it's Work I get the values of the cells but I can not recover the values anymore  **let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(firstName: "\(sub["firstname"])", lastName: "\(sub["lastname"])")**

Comment: What do you mean? Could you be more explicit? What do you need `firstname` and `lastname` for?

Comment: I want to display the lastname and name (in a tableview that I have customized) and I have the options in the tableview cell so your solution updates the information contained in the tableview cell but not the custom menu header (contain lastname and name) `let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(firstName: "(sub["firstname"])", lastName: "(sub["lastname"])")` I dont know if you understand me

Comment: Can you show me the code of the **HPMenuHeaderViewModel** please?

Comment: how to reload data?? `let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(firstName: "(sub["firstname"])", lastName: "(sub["lastname"])")`

Comment: I'm asking for the code inside of the **HPMenuHeaderViewModel** and **HPMenuViewModel** custom classes.

Comment: I post the code at the bottom.. the problem is that it does not display the lastname, name.. same when I put the static values

Comment: how to reload the data from the uilabel? because it just refreshes the cell data. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

in **HPMenuHeaderViewModel** class

```
class HPMenuHeaderViewModel: NSObject {
    var imageName: UIImage?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var numberString: String?
    var name: String {
        return String.safe(firstName) + " " + String.safe(lastName)
    }
    var nameInitials: String {
        let arrayName = self.name.components(separatedBy: " ")
        return  arrayName.reduce("") { $0.safePrefix(1)  + $1.safePrefix(1)}
    }
    @objc init(firstName: String, lastName: String, numberString: String) {
        super.init()
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName =  lastName
        self.numberString = numberString
    }
}
```

in **HPMenuViewModel** class

```
class HPMenuViewModel: NSObject {
    var titlePage: String?
    var accountTableViewCellModel: [HPMenuTableViewCellModel]?
    var headerMenuViewModel: HPMenuHeaderViewModel?
    init(titlePage: String, array accountTableViewCellModel: [HPMenuTableViewCellModel]?, headerMenuViewModel: HPMenuHeaderViewModel ) {
      super.init()
      self.titlePage = titlePage
      self.accountTableViewCellModel = accountTableViewCellModel
      self.headerMenuViewModel = headerMenuViewModel
    }
}
```

I use MVVM architecture